# How to bind a property to another property (with INotifyPropertyChanged)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an application in MVVM architecture. It has a set of DomainModels classes, each of which implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. The data is updated according to its internal logic.

The program has a display of some data on the View with a binding to the ViewModel.
I want to separate the View from the implementation details of the DomainModel (and at the same time bring it in line with the Law of Demeter).

Now

```
<StatusBarItem Visibility="{Binding Status.Connected, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SystemTime.Time, StringFormat='HH:mm:ss dd.MM.yyyy'}"/>
</StatusBarItem>
```

Want

```
<StatusBarItem Visibility="{Binding Connected, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SystemTime, StringFormat='HH:mm:ss dd.MM.yyyy'}"/>
</StatusBarItem>
```

CommunityToolkit.Mvvm has a similar attribute:

```
[NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(FullName))]
private string? name;
```

It notifies FullName change when Name changes

But I need the opposite - notify the SystemTime change in the ViewModel when the Time in the DomainModel changes.

However, I do not want the DomainModel to know anything about the ViewModel (from my point of view this is also a bad architectural decision, the model should not know about the view)

I tried to do it by manually subscribing to change events like this

```
public class StatusBarViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private readonly DomainDataService _dataService;

    public long Speed => _statusService.Speed;
    public bool Connected => _statusService.Connected;
    public DateTime SystemTime => _dataService.SystemTime.Time;

    public StatusBarViewModel(DomainDataService dataService)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;
        _statusService = statusService;
        _statusService.PropertyChanged += (_, args) =>
        {
            switch (args.PropertyName)
            {
                case nameof(_statusService.Speed):
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Speed));
                    break;
                case nameof(_statusService.Connected):
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Connected));
                    break;
            }
        };
        _dataService.SystemTime.PropertyChanged += (_, args) =>
        {
            if(args.PropertyName == nameof(_dataService.SystemTime.Time))
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SystemTime));
        };
    }
}
```

But I'm afraid of the bulkiness of the solution and the possible impact on performance with a large number of properties. Is there a more elegant way to "bridge" between properties that I've missed?

Update 1.

At the moment the ViewModel looks like this

```
public class StatusBarViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public SystemTime SystemTime { get; }
    public ConnectionStatusService Status { get; }

    public StatusBarViewModel(DomainDataService dataService, ConnectionStatusService statusService)
    {
        SystemTime = dataService.SystemTime;
        Status = statusService;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"But I need the opposite - notify the SystemTime change in the ViewModel when the Time in the DomainModel changes."* - Simply allow the ViewModel class to observe a SystemTimeChanged event raised by the DomainModel.

Comment: Additionally you should set the DataContext of the StatusBarItem properly. If you design your view model objects better you don't have to use nested property paths. It seems you should fix your class design instead of trying to do some magic using XAML.

Comment: @BionicCode. There is no SystemTimeChanged event. However, this is the same as subscribing to the general PropertyChanged event (just one event instead of many, but the meaning is the same). The DataContext for StatusBarView is StatusBarVIewModel. What do you mean by fix class design? I'm not talking about XAML magic, I'm talking about ViewModel design

Comment: I was trying to say that you should spend your view model a SystemTimeChanged  event. Your view model classes obviously don't reflect the actual DataContext. The view has to assemble the DataContext by resolving nested property paths. Instead all relevant data should reside in the same class defied at top level. If this class uses composition you can delegate property access to the composition classes. For example: `public boo IsEnabled { get => this.Dependency.IsEnabled; set => this.Dependency.IsEnabled = value; }`.

Comment: It's difficult to tell where exactly your class design is wrong without knowing the details. But from your problem we can tell that it is not optimal. You basically mentioned the solution yourself. Fix your code to follow the Law of Demeter. You just misinterpreted the principle and instead of trying to fix your class design you wanted to fix your XAML code.

Comment: Well, the nature of time is: it changes at any time. I guess you are looking for something that will notify, when the seconds part of time changes. You can use a timer to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a more elegant way to "bridge" between properties that I've missed?

Not really. The model raises an event that the view model subscribes to. You could possibly inject the publisher (model) and the observer (view model) with an [event aggregator](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/) or messenger to avoid tight coupling between the types, but your current solution of adding en event handler in the view model is perfectly fine.